# Release Memory in Work with Datasets

Tags: c#, performance, dataset

1. I load some data from SQL server into a `DataSet`.
2. When I close the form my `DataSet` is not releasing memory!

How Can I Fix this problem?

Comment: I Check it with Windows Task Manager!!!

Comment: That doesn't deserve '!!!', rather it puts '???' after your conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to answer your question as you did not post your code.  Perhaps, this memory leak is caused by the fact that this dataSet is referenced on another form or there are event handlers.... To find memory leaks, I would suggest that you try the [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/).  Finally, to explicitly clear the DataSet, use its Dispose method.

Answer (score 1):

You have a live reference to your DataSet.
You need to figure out what is still referencing the DataSet and clear the reference.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure there is no reference to your data set, also make sure after you are done with the dataset you call the dispose method (or put your data set in a using block)